# bash script submodule foreach not working

Tags: git, bash

I have the following bash script

```
IGNORE=("test" "jaja");
git submodule foreach --recursive "if [[ \"${IGNORE[@]}\" =~ \"$name\" ]] ; then echo \"skipped\"; else npm install; fi"
```

For some reason the `[[ \"${IGNORE[@]}\" =~ \"$name\" ]]` does not work. When I put the IGNORE array inside the foreach, it works. Does anyone know why?

This works:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'IGNORE=("test" "jaja"); if [[ "${IGNORE[@]}" =~ "$name" ]] ; then echo "skipped"; else npm install; fi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array expansion produces two separate words:

```
$ IGNORE=("test" "jaja")
$ printf "%s\n" "if [[ \"${IGNORE[@]}\" =~ \"$name\" ]] ; then echo \"skipped\"; else npm install; fi"
if [[ "test
jaja" =~ "" ]] ; then echo "skipped"; else npm install; fi
```

An `@` expansion as part of a larger string usually won't do what you expect.

Switching to `*` should produce the same result, but then it isn't clear why you are using an array instead of a simple parameter.

```
$ printf "%s\n" "if [[ \"${IGNORE[*]}\" =~ \"$name\" ]] ; then echo \"skipped\"; else npm install; fi"
if [[ "test jaja" =~ "" ]] ; then echo "skipped"; else npm install; fi
```